# Creating a Web Crawler in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web, web-crawler, jsoup

I am creating a web crawler using Java EE Technologies. I have created a crawler service which contains the result of the WebCrawler in term `CrawlerElement` objects which contains information of interest to me.

Currently I am using `JSOUP` Library in order to do this. But it is not reliable I am attempting the connection three times and also timeout is 10seconds still It is unreliable.

By unreliable I mean even if it can be accessed publicly, It can not be accessed by the crawler program. I know it could be due to `robots.txt` exclusion but in that also it is allowed but still it is unrealiable.

So I decided to go with `URLConnection` object which has `openConnection` and then `connect` method for doing this.

I have one more requirement which is bugging me and that is : I have to get the response time in milliseconds for a CrawlerElement which means how many seconds it took to load page B from Page A?? and I checked the methods of URLConnection there is no way out in order to do that.

Any ideas in that topic? Can anyone help me?

I was thinking writing a code before and after which takes current time in milliseconds before the gettingContent code and current time in milliseconds subtract and save that milliseconds in database but I was thing whether it would be accurate or not?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : CURRENT IMPLEMENTATION

Current Implementation which gives me statusCode, contentType etc..

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


public class GetContent {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/faq/faq0079.html");
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
    uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic bG9hbnNkZXY6bG9AbnNkM3Y=");
    uc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
    uc.connect();
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(endTime - startTime);
    String contentType = uc.getContentType();
    System.out.println(contentType);
    String statusCode = uc.getHeaderField(0);
    System.out.println(statusCode);     
   }
}
```

what say is it okay to do this way or I should use heavy API's like Apache HttpClient or Apache Nutch..

Comment: Subtracting the times before and after sounds pretty accurate to me.

Comment: Thanks Danny. I think for load time I will use subtraction method itself. I have to think about which method to use for getting the contents actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK it means you have did work and getting problems in that API/Library.I know it is terrifying  to build one thing and then waste that all code and shift to another one but if it would be possible for you As `JSoup` is just a parser library and it may cause some more problems to you in future so I suggest you to use these [more stable API](http://java-source.net/open-source/crawlers/java-web-crawler).You can also use [crawler4j](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/) for that purpose.
Here is [the list of some open source crawler API's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Open-source_crawlers) and by doing some R&D you can find a good solution for this :)

Answer (score 3):

It's better to use proven frameworks than reinvent the wheel. Try Apache Nutch(I recommend 1.x branch, 2.x seems to be too raw). It will be a lot of pain to implement own crawler with supporting of parallelism, robots.txt / "noindex" metatag, redirects, reliability... There are so many issues to solve.

Comment: Hi, Decided to go with HtmlUnit API which can be found here: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/ and it also has a load time feature. basically it is meant for testing but it has all the things which I need. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Apache HttpClient library.  I've had good results with it.  It seems to be a good bit better for HTTP specific communications.

Comment: I thought about this library but I don't know I was unsure, will it support HTTPS??

Comment: Yes, it seems to have pretty good support, although its a little verbose its not too bad.